# Docker command (cli) defaulting to port instead of socket

Tags: docker

I've changed the docker daemon to listen on port eg: `/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` Now when I execute the command docker it hangs on. So what I need is to execute `docker -H :2375 <command>`.

Is there any way how to setup docker command (cli) to automatically use the port not the socket (so when I call docker ps it will call docker -H :2375 ps)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following in your environment (see the [cli documentation for more options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/)):

```
export DOCKER_HOST=127.0.0.1:2375
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881876/shipyard-not-showing-containers-after-docker-daemon-switch-to-tcp-port)?