# Shipyard not showing containers after docker daemon switch to TCP port

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've switched docker daemon to listen on TCP port ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881599/docker-command-cli-defaulting-to-port-instead-of-socket/37881686)). Docker command (cli) is already working, but when I run shipyard with [this docker-compose](https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) I don't see any image which was visible before. Should I change something in the docker-compose or this won't work ever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to configure the service (in my case on CentOs)

creating file
`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`
with content

`[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H fd:// --insecure-registry 10.0.1.70:5000`

and reloading and restarting the daemon did the trick.

so I have both tcp and ?filedscriptor?